# .htacces rule to remove extension and forward all requests to single page

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

**I want to**:

- remove `.php` extension from url
- redirect `.php` to non extension version
- forward all requests to `/`, except `/login` (preferably wildcard forward)

**Example Cases**:

- `/login => /login`
- `/dashboard => /`
- `/settings => /`
- `/profile => /`
- `/settings => /`
- `/products => /`
- `/products/example => /`
- `/products/example/test => /`

**.htaccess code**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dashboard  / [NC,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**What it does**:

- redirect `/dashboard` to `/`
- makes `.php` file accessible without extension

**NOTE**:

- 404 will be handled in php so everything should be forward to `/`
- want to keep url in browser, for example, `/dashboard` should show `dashboard` path in address bar but only forward request to `/`